# First experience with asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am learning `python-asyncio`, and I'm trying to write a simple model.

I have a function handling tasks. While handling, it goes to another remote service for data and then prints a message.

My code:

```
dd = 0

@asyncio.coroutine
def slow_operation():
    global dd
    dd += 1
    print('Future is started!', dd)
    yield from asyncio.sleep(10 - dd)  # request to another server
    print('Future is done!', dd)

def add():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        asyncio.ensure_future(slow_operation(), loop=loop)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.Future()
asyncio.ensure_future(slow_operation(), loop=loop)
th.Thread(target=add).start()
loop.run_forever()
```

But this code doesn't switch the context while sleeping in:

```
yield from asyncio.sleep(10 - dd)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: ty @Mogsdad for your fixes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[asyncio.ensure_future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.ensure_future) is not thread-safe, that's why `slow_operation` tasks are not started when they should be. Use [loop.call_soon_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.call_soon_threadsafe):

```
    callback = lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(slow_operation(), loop=loop)
    loop.call_soon_threadsafe(cb)
```

Or [asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) if you're running python 3.5.1:

```
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(slow_operation(), loop)
```

However, you should probably keep the use of threads to the minimum. Unless you use a library running tasks in its own thread, all the code should run inside the event loop (or inside an executor, see [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor)).